# Magento2: How to send email to all admin users?

Tags: magento2, email, ajax

I have listed all the reviews of the merchant in the frontend.
I want to remove the particular review from the list. So I have added a remove request button.

When a merchant clicks on a button an email should be send to all admin users.

I have implemented this on ajax call.

But I am not able to achieve this in Magento2

My Code:

view.phtml file:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession    = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
//$customer_name      = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
$getMerchantid        = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    if (!empty($getMerchantid)) 
    {?>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

      <?php 
        $collection = $block->getReviewList();
      //echo $collection->count();
            // $collection = $objectManager->create('Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Feedback')->getCollection()
      // ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',$getMerchantid);
      //  echo "<pre>";
            //  print_r($collection);
      //  echo "</pre>";
      ?>
      <?php if(count($collection) > 0){?>


        <div class="title-review"><span>Reviews</span></div>
        <?php 

      // check the count of the collection 
        }  else { ?><p class="empty_record">No Reviews Found</p> <?php } ?>

        <form class="" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>marketplace/account/review" method="get">
        <div class ="table-responsive">
        <table>                 
          <tbody>
            <?php 
            $i = 1;    
            foreach ($collection as $key => $data):?>
            <tr id="rules_<?php echo $data['entity_id']; ?>">
              <td rowspan="2" width="2%" data-th="Title" class="col code">
              <?php
              $num_padded = sprintf("%02d",$i++);
              echo $num_padded;
              ?>
              </td>
              <td width="20%">
                <strong>Rating</strong> <br/>

            <?php

            $starNumbervalue = round(($data['feed_price']/20), 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

            for ($x = 1; $x <= $starNumbervalue; $x++) {
                echo '<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>';
            }
            if (strpos($starNumbervalue, '.')) {
                echo '<li><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></li>';
                $x++;
            }
            while ($x <= 5) {
                echo '<li><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></li>';
                $x++;
            }?>
            <?php echo round(($data['feed_price']/20), 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); ?>                    
              </td>
                            <td width="58%" data-th="Anchor" class="col amount">
                                <strong>Feed Review</strong><br/>
                                <?php echo $data['feed_review']; ?>
                            </td>
              <td rowspan="2" width="20%" class="btn_remove">
                  <button class="search_btn delete_review_ratings" width="20" data-id="<?php echo $data['entity_id']; ?>" title="Remove">Remove Request</button>

              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td width="200px">
                <strong>Customer Name</strong><br/>
                <?php echo $data['feed_nickname']; ?>
              </td>

              <td colspan="2" class="status_sec">
                <div width="200px">
                  <strong>Created</strong><br/>
                  <?php
                     $createdAt = $data['created_at'];
                     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                     $DateLoader = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');
                     $createdAt = $DateLoader->date(new \DateTime($createdAt));
                     echo $dateAsString = $createdAt->format('F j, Y h:i:s a');
                  ?>
                 <br/>
                  <!-- 10:32:56 am -->
                </div>
                <div width="200px">
                  <strong>Status</strong><br/>
                       <?php 
                        if ($data['status'] == 1) 
                        {
                          echo "Approved";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          echo "Disapproved";
                        }
                        ?>
                </div>
              </td>             
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  require([
   "jquery", 
   "mage/calendar" 
   ], 
 function($)
 {
 $(".delete_review_ratings").click(function () 
    {
      var removeReviewId =  $(this).attr('data-id');
      if (removeReviewId != '') 
      {
        $.ajax(
        {
          type: "POST",
          url:  "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'customajax/index/'?>",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {removeReviewId: removeReviewId},
          beforeSend:function()
          {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to send remove request?");
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
          },
          success: function (data) 
          {
            alert("You request has been sent successfully");
            //$("#rules_"+removeReviewId).remove();   
          }
        });
      }
    });
});

</script>
```

controller ajax file:

```
<?php

namespace Amy\CustomAjax\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

//class Deletereviewratings extends Action

class Deletereviewratings extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

{

   protected $_userFactory;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    UserCollectionFactory $userFactory
   ) {

        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "got review ratings";


        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        $helper = $this->_objectManager->get('Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data');

        $sellerName = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
        $sellerEmail = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();


        $adminStoremail = $helper->getAdminEmailId();
        $adminEmail = $adminStoremail ? $adminStoremail : $helper->getDefaultTransEmailId();

        $emailTemplateVariables = [];
        $senderInfo = [];
        $receiverInfo = [];
        $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = $adminUsername;
        $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = $sellerName;

        $senderInfo = [
            'name' => $sellerName,
            'email' => $sellerEmail,
        ];
        $receiverInfo = [

            'email' => $adminEmail,
        ];

        $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Email'
        )->sendRemoveReviewRequestMail(
            $emailTempVariables,
            $senderInfo,
            $receiverInfo
        );

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Your email has been sent successfully.'));

     }


}

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found an answer on my own, may be useful to others:

```
<?php

namespace Amy\CustomAjax\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

class Deletereviewratings extends Action

{

   //protected $_userFactory;
    protected $transportBuilder;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    //UserCollectionFactory $userFactory
   ) {

        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        //$this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "got review ratings";

        $getReviewId         = $this->getRequest()->getParam('removeReviewId');
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('marketplace_datafeedback');
        $read = "Select * FROM " . $tableName . " where entity_id=" . $getReviewId;

        $result = $connection->fetchAll($read);
        $postData = $result[0];
        $feedId =$postData['entity_id'];
        $feedreview =$postData['feed_review'];
        $feedsellerID =$postData['seller_id'];


        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession    = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
        $customer_name      = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $userModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\User\Model\User')->getCollection();
        foreach ($userModel as $value) {
        $adminEmail = $value['email'];
        $adminName = $value['firstname'];


        $consumer_email = "sample@gmail.com";
        $requestData['mail_subj'] = "Remove Review Request From Seller";
        $requestData['hello_txt'] = "Hello " . $adminName;
        $requestData['message'] = "Please check the New Seller Review Remove request listed below.";
        $requestData['feedreview'] = $feedreview ;
        $requestData['sellerid'] = $feedsellerID ;
        $requestData['sellername'] = $customer_name ;
        $postObj = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObj->setData($requestData);

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('marketplace_email_review_remove_request_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObj])
            ->setFrom(['name' => "Remove Review Request From Merchant", 'email' => $consumer_email])
            ->addTo($adminEmail)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();


        }


     }


}

?>
```